# Only take numbers inside parentheses (brackets)

Tags: php, preg-replace

Using the code below,

```
$string = 'd.c part2 15245 (30)';
$string2 = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string);
echo $string2;
```

output: `21524530`

How would I only take the numbers inside parentheses (brackets)

so that the output is `30`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match`:

```
$string = 'd.c part2 15245 (30)';
preg_match('/\((\d+)\)/', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => (30)
    [1] => 30
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$re = '/\((\d+)\)/ix';
$str = 'd.c part2 15245 (30)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```